# Передать вызвавший обьект в this вызванной функции

Tags: javascript, promise, discord

Я видел раньше похожий код:

```
let prompt = await msg.channel.send(promptMessage).confirmationHandler();
```

`send` возвращает Promise с обьектом отправленного сообщения, к которому потом можно прикрепить реакции или просто получить его `id`. Я хотел отправить его прямиком в следующую функцию и я видел подобное раньше, где обьект до `.` (`send(promptMessage).`) можно было вызвать прямиком из `this` в следующей функции.

`confirmationHandler` это функция возвращающая Proise, начинается так:

```
function confirmationHandler() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

    //add reactions first
    await this.react('✅'); //по сути this = prompt в моем понимании
    await this.react('❌');
```

Ошибка на первом же `this` ибо не был передан:

> TypeError: this.react is not a function

Мне кажется нужно использовать `prototype` но я не совсем понимаю как это делать в моем случае.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно вызвать `confirmationHandler()` так, чтобы его `this` было объектом, в который разрешается Promise, возвращённая `msg.channel.send(promptMessage)`?

Если именно это нужно, можно так:

```js
let prompt = await confirmationHandler.call(await msg.channel.send(promptMessage));
```

Не очень красиво, но ваш вариант не сработает, если у упомянутого объекта нет метода `confirmationHandler()`.

Правда, по вашему вопросу не совсем понятно, должен ли `prompt` быть одновременно и `this` в `confirmationHandler()`, и возвращаемым значением.

Comment: Да, мой метод не работает потому я тут. И да, вы правильно поняли. Не очень красиво но это уже вариант! Спасибо

Comment: "должен ли prompt быть одновременно и this в confirmationHandler(), и возвращаемым значением" - нет. Сообщение передается только с `confirmationHandler` а уже его результат в `prompt`.